# Installing Pulp 1.4.8 Error

Tags: python-3.x, installation, linear-programming, pulp

I have followed the instructions at https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html for installing Pulp on Windows "from source". I know I am in the right directory, but for some reason when I enter

```
setup.py install
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to create process using '/usr/bin/env/python "C:\Users\Cassey W\Desktop\PuLP-1.4.8\setup.py"  install'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, as I have followed the instructions to the letter.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6? It seems that starting with Python3.3 and 3.6 there are Python Launchers for Windows. Try prefacing the command with `py` like so,  `py setup.py install` [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-the-command-line), or maybe by specifying the python version `py -3 setup.py install` (http://learning-python.com/py33-windows-launcher.html)

Comment: Any specific reason to install froum sources? ```pip install pulp``` should work on windows (does for me) and it seems the sources are outdated too. It seems those links there are quite old. The current sources are [here](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) (and using these, install from sources actually installs a newer version than pip install).

Comment: I would recommend `pip install pulp` for beginners, It looks like you are getting some strange interaction with the new bash shell in windows

Comment: `pip install pulp` worked, thanks so much!